# In VS2010 check-in confirmation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

Previously visual studio is telling me how many files i am to check-in and asking me to confirm first prior to check-in.  Now, when i press "check-in"... it just checks-in without asking.

I cannot find the configuration where to enable the confirmation.  Does anybody know?

Cheers!

Comment: Can anyone help help me find this feature in VS2008 if it is there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

sOpen your Visual Studio

**Tools->Options->Source Control ->Visual Studio team Foundation Server**

And make sure that an option

**“Prompt before check-in from Pending Changes windows”** is **Checked**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks... I see my problem this is only available in VS2010 not in VS2008 where I was looking for it also.  Either way you are correct on VS2010.  Somehow i wish this was on VS2008...